# D3 visualization from Hbase using REST api/json

Tags: rest, d3.js, base64, hbase

I have a standalone Vbox setup with hortonworks sandbox. And I have an HBASE table called 'mytable' and column family 'cf'.
REST service is started and I can curl through ssh to 127.0.0.1 address to get the data in Base64 encoded format as JSON.
Need some help on visualizing this JSON using D3.js. What url I should use to pull the encoded JSON through rest API into a D3 file. Can somebody point out a simple example.

Comment: Take your pick: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This got to be one of the strangest use-cases for HBase I've ever seen... Please notice that **HBase REST API* should never be accessible from clients**.

What you can do is create a small web service/API in your preferred programming language with access to the HBase REST API, fetch all the information needed from HBase (by performing gets or opening a scanner), and format it in a way that works for D3 (which I don't know what is). Then, you need to perform the proper changes to your frontend/client-side code to request the data from your intermediate API instead of directly querying HBase.

There are plenty of API documentation and examples here: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate

*HBase REST API is also known as STARGATE

*If you update the question with more information I'll gladly try to improve my answer.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is what I was looking for. Initially I started with HBASE REST -> custom webservice approach and then confused with some documentation online .  I am putting a whole lot of effort for learning end to end.Appreciate the help.

Comment: NP, documentation can be overwhelming and confusing, the point is that you're always going to need some sort of middleware app to interact with HBase. Please take your time to accept the response if you consider your question has been solved :)